# Print all anagrams together in a sentence in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, interview-questions

I know a lot of memory is being used, but how do I make this more efficient in space(and time) .

```
   public class AnagramsTogether {


    public static String getAnagramsTogether(String sentence){

        if(sentence == null || sentence.trim().equals("")) return null;

        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
        HashMap<String,List<String>> map =new HashMap<String,List<String>>();


        for(String word:words)
        {
            char[] wordArray = word.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(wordArray);

            List<String> tempList = map.get(new String(wordArray));
            if(tempList == null) tempList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            tempList.add(word);
                            map.put(new String(wordArray),tempList);
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet())
        {

            for(String item:entry.getValue()){
                result.append(item+ " ");
            }
        }


        return result.toString();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(getAnagramsTogether("cat dog act tac god"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Whitespace discipline

While your indentation is good, the placement of whitespace isn't very good yet. In Java, we tend to put whitespace after keywords and before braces. A beautifier with standard settings would make your code more readable already.

## Use the most common type that still does the job.

For example, your variable `map` should be declared as `Map`, not `HashMap`.

## Smarter Use of `Map` API

Instead of getting the list, checking whether it's `null` and if it isn't `null`, creating it, and then always putting it, you could use `Map.computeIfAbsent()`, like this:

```
map
    .computeIfAbsent(normalizedAnagram, s -> ArrayList::new)
    .add(word);
```

## Split your logic

Your function `getAnagramsTogether` is doing many things. You could split it into multiple methods. For example, you could have a separate method `normalizeAnagram()` which takes a `String` and returns a new `String` with the characters sorted.

## Bug in your call to `Arrays.sort(char[] wordArray)`

It should be noted that `char` is NOT a character. It is a UTF-16 fragment. For the first Unicode plane, i.e. code points with values that can be represented by 16 bits, `char` is a character. But for code points with higher values, a `char` contains only part of the character, and the way how you construct the normalized anagram is tearing characters apart.

It may not matter to you, as probably all relevant words in your use cases would have code points in the 16 bit plane.

## Don't use `+` in `StringBuilder.append()`

You should be consistent, either use `+` or `append()`.
But using `+` inside `StringBuilder.append()` doesn't make sense.
We use `StringBuilder` in order to have `String`-concatenation which is faster and uses less memory than using `+`. Using `+` in an argument to `StringBuilder.append()` is completely contrary to the intention of using `StringBuilder` in the first place.

## Don't construct the same object twice.

You're calling `new String(wordArray)` twice for no good reason.
You could just create a single `String normalizedAnagram` and use that.

## Consider a smarter way of String concatenation.

The following code concatenates your final Map into a String in a smarter way:

```
map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "))
```

Answer (score 4):

### Use `String.isEmpty` instead of `.equals("")`

> ```
> if(sentence == null || sentence.trim().equals("")) return null;
> ```

Comparing a string with a empty string is slower than using `isEmpty()` because the first step in comparing a string getting the size of BOTH strings.

```
if(sentence == null || sentence.trim().isEmpty()) return null;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Returning null**

You should throw an exception instead of returning null. Returning null is almost never a good idea.

**Using java 8:**

If you have java 8 available you can use streams:

```
   public static String getAnagramsTogether2(String sentence)
   {
       if(sentence == null ||  sentence.trim().isEmpty()) 
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();

       Map<String, List<String>> map =Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
                                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                   AnagramsTogether::sortString));

       return map.values()
                 .stream()
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
   }
   public static String sortString(String string) {

       return  string.chars()
                     .sorted()
                     .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
                              StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, 
                              StringBuilder::append)
                     .toString();          
   }
```

Comment: i'm kinda new to java 8 but this reduces the size of code like crazy !:)

Comment: @MAG Do you mind explaining the "magic" of sortString?